# Is the sentence semantically correct?

Tags: sentence, semantics, sentence-meaning

I have a quick question: is this question semantically correct?

***This approach is not only based on X, but it even enhances this technology.***

I'm quite confused, because if something enhances something, it's quite logical that it has to be based on it in order to advance it? Or am I overthinking right now?

Best,
Kate

Comment: It's not properly ordered. 'Not only is this approach based on X, it actually enhances this technology.'

Answer (score 1):

If an idea or technique enhances subject or technology, or way of doing a thing, then it is implicitly about that technology. Something that improves farming techniques is about that and not about rocket technology or oil painting. The sentence seems a bit redundant for this reason but is semantically correct.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking so, that the part "is not only based on" is actually redundant. I think that if I want to say e.g. "This approach is not only based on X, but it even enhances Y technology" seems to be the perfect example for this type of concerns. Anyways, thanks a lot for clearing it up!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is redundant.

For instance, you can have an approach based on X (Which I'm assuming is the technology), that does not enhance the technology but is merely an application of it.

Stating that it both applies the technology and improves on it seems valid to me. Perhaps if you used "just" instead of "only", it might make things a bit clearer?

Semantically, I see nothing wrong with the sentence either way.

Comment: Looks like there is not only one correct answer to this question. Thank you!